# How to run AWS ECS Task overriding environment variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, aws-cli, amazon-ecs

To override environment variables via CLI we may use `--overrides (structure)` according to [AWS ECS Commandline Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html).

How to pass name value pairs (structure or JSON) in command line?

```
[
  { "name" : "NAME", "value" : "123" },
  { "name" : "DATE", "value" : "1234-12-12" },
  { "name" : "SCRIPT", "value" : "123456" }
]
```

I'm looking for a way to override above environment variables using AWS ECS CLI. 
Something like:

```
aws ecs run-task --overrides <<just environment vars here>> --task-definition ...
```

Documentation is not clear. I googled but couldn't help.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You have to provide a JSON document as documented under the [`--overrides` option](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html).

```
{
  "containerOverrides": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "command": ["string", ...],
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
        ...
      ]
    }
    ...
  ],
  "taskRoleArn": "string"
}
```

You have to specify the `name` of the container to get the environment override, and specify a list of `environment` key-value pairs.

You can specify the JSON document in-line with your argument or pass a file path argument to the task. I will show both ways.

#### Passing JSON in-line

Your command would look like this (fill in the value `CONTAINER_NAME_FROM_TASK`).

```
aws ecs run-task --overrides '{ "containerOverrides": [ { "name": "CONTAINER_NAME_FROM_TASK", "environment": [ { "name": "NAME", "value": "123" }, { "name": "DATE", "value": "1234-12-12" }, { "name": "SCRIPT", "value": "123456" } ] } ] }' --task-definition (...)
```

That does look rather ugly though, and would be annoying to edit. It also only works on Unix-y systems and would require quote escaping in Windows.

So alternatively, you can pass a file path to the AWS CLI and have it load your override JSON from a file.

### Passing a file path argument

Create a file, let's call it `overrides.json`, and put the same JSON into it:

```
{
    "containerOverrides": [{
        "name": "CONTAINER_NAME_FROM_TASK",
        "environment": [{
            "name": "NAME",
            "value": "123"
        }, {
            "name": "DATE",
            "value": "1234-12-12"
        }, {
            "name": "SCRIPT",
            "value": "123456"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then, assuming your file is in the **current directory**:

```
aws ecs run-task --overrides file://overrides.json --task-definition (..)
```

If your file is **elsewhere in the filesystem** and you're on a **Linux/Unix-y system**:

```
aws ecs run-task --overrides file:///path/to/overrides.json --task-definition (..)
```

If your file is **elsewhere in the filesystem** and you're doing this in **Windows**:

```
aws ecs run-task --overrides file://DRIVE_LETTER:\path\to\overrides.json --task-definition (..)
```

Comment: Does terraform document this behavior anywhere? I can only find file() function which is not the same as you describe: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html

Comment: @Ievgen No, because this is not a terraform behavior, it's the AWS CLI. If you want the Terraform equivalent, you specify something as part of [`container_definitions`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html#container_definitions) when creating your ECS Task Definition.

Comment: i dont see a way to override image name. Is that correct?

Comment: @РАВИ you can not override the image via `containerOverrides` - `image` is a property of the container itself. Think of `containerOverrides` more as "apply these resource/environment changes to an already configured contained."

Comment: Are overrides options available in ECS console?

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to 逆さま's answer. You might also want to add the details of the cluster. When I ran the above I got a `ClusterNotFoundException`.

This worked for me:

`aws ecs run-task --overrides file://overrides.json --task-definition (..) --cluster (..)`

Comment: Try commenting on answers when you wish to add to them rather than write another answer. Your comment will actually follow the answer and be seen more appropriately :).